# Using the normal distribution in real life

Tags: normal-distribution, references, teaching

I am looking for examples of where the normal distribution has been used in published journals or other real data sets.

To add some context, I teach A-level (16-18) Maths and I would like to include examples from acadedmic papers - to give students a flavour of academic research. Most of the examples that I have found use contrived examples or use made up data. Ideally I would like to find examples about any of the following techniques:

- Normal cdf and pdf functions
- finding the mean and / or standard deviation given specific cdf values
- approximating a binomial distribution
- hypothesis test to decide if the mean has changed

It might be helpful to include an example from another area of the maths course. When studying exponential models, [this BMC Biology article](https://bmcbiol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1741-7007-10-60/figures/1) provided an example of log-log relationships using real data, namely body mass and femur length in various animals.

Comment: This is perfectly on-topic here, but perhaps answers provided on the math educators SE would be more helpful, because this question is squarely about math education. https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See also the similar https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33776/real-life-examples-of-common-distributions, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401055/are-there-any-examples-of-a-variable-being-normally-distributed-that-is-not-du, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49212/importance-of-normal-distribution,